# How to clear cache above 23 api in android

Tags: android, exception, caching, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-7.0-nougat

I am using IPackageDataObserver.class for removing cache, it is working till android 5.1.1 but not for android 6.0.1. and above. As it is deprecated for the above versions and gives security exception and Method.Invocation exception. Now I have seen apps that are clearing cache for android 6.0.1 and above like clean master. May be they are using accessibility and I don't know much about accessibility. So can anyone help me with this or suggest some other way for removing the cache memory.

Comment: read from here https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: post the logcat error

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod: Already added the permissions. But they are not working

Comment: @AtplMohali ask permission at run time  because Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app

Comment: I have implemented these permissions.
ReadExternalStorage, WriteExternalStorage, ClearCache, PhoneState and are implemented at the run time